# call files with foreign name vb.net, c# and asp

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, file

i create sites and desktop programs that call files like (image - pdf - video )
but the files has foreign name like "Dr._Laura_Véccia V'agliéri.jpg" 
or has special character ,So most of time i doesn't work

when i call it like in site like

```
<img src="Dr._Laura_Véccia V'agliéri.jpg" />
```

or like

```
Try 

  Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("Dr._Laura_Véccia V'agliéri.jpg")
  Dim line = Await sr.ReadToEndAsync()
  ResultBlock.Text = line
End Using 
Catch
   ResultBlock.Text = "Could not read the file" 
End Try
```

is there a way that i can call it right without change the file name

Answer (score 0):

StreamReader in Framework 4.5 and using NTFS does correctly handle UNICODE compliant file strings such as the file name you presented and thus you are able to use special characters like é and '.

Here is tested code that succeeds in reading a text file with the file name you specified.

```
Async Sub ReadCharacters()
    Dim result As String

    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("c:\\users\\path\\Dr._Laura_Véccia V'agliéri.jpg.txt")
        Console.WriteLine("Opened file.")
        result = Await reader.ReadToEndAsync()
        Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + result)
    End Using
End Sub
```

What I believe is happening is that stream reader is throwing you an error after it unsuccessfully tries to auto detect the encoding on your jpeg. SteamReader is actually intended for text streams.

For .jpgs you are best off using [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) as this will avoid any encoding problems in your file altogether.